# Disable link for single posts

Tags: posts

I'm working on a website where everything happens in the homepage.
There you can see the posts in a list; but I don't want users to be able to browse the posts.

Is there a way to disable or block URLs for posts?

Comment: You can remove the link in the theme template? Unless you're looking for a method that doesn't involve code? This is a programming stack though. Or are you asking how to prevent users directly visiting the URL if it's shared with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you can either disable click events using CSS.

   ```
   .linkclass {     pointer-events: none;}
   ```
2. Or better Modify the template and remove the part which creates anchor links for titles.

note: with the above, it is still possible to access the page by directly putting the full URL in the browser. if you want to completely remove the single page.

```php
add_action('register_post_type_args', function ($args, $postType) {
    if ($postType !== 'post'){
        return $args;
    }

    $args['publicly_queryable'] = false;
  

    return $args;
}, 99, 2);
```